# Preventing Enter from Submitting form in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have the following code on my page:

```
$('form.enter-doesnt-submit').submit(function () {
    console.log($(document.activeElement));
    if($(document.activeElement).attr('type') == 'submit') {
        console.log
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("Prevented enter from submitting the form.");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Which I'm fairly certain I got from stackoverflow a long time ago.  It works fine, just not in Safari.  The reason being that when I log out `document.activeElement` it gives me the *entire page*, so of course the attribute type is not submit and therefore the form doesnt submit even when you are clicking the submit button.

I need to be able to prevent enter submitting on my form because they are online tests, and if the user is writing an answer and accidentally presses enter before the form is complete then they are marked incorrectly as they didn't actually finish the test.

Can anyone help me with some way of preventing enter from being pressed on Safari?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved this by coming at it in another way, by targeting the inputs in the form instead:

```
$('form.enter-doesnt-submit input[type=text]').keypress(function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault()
    }
});
```

Pressing enter in a textarea doesnt submit a form by default, so its just the inputs that need preventing.  Now my submit button works in safari and in chrome.